# In what lifecycle point are tests ignored when building?

Tags: maven

I am trying to understand the maven build lifecycle when it is regarding to tests:
Let's say I have a project with a class in the src/main folder and another one in the src/test. When I run mvn install, it get's compiled, then tested, then packaged and installed.

Until now I thought that maven would not package the tests in the snapshot, because this is not "production" code. Is this true?
In this case, **when does maven ignores the test files?**

Comment: Yes, it is true. It does not package the tests unless you use some plugin to do so. Read it here: [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Simple answer to your question is Yes. Tests are not production so it does not make sense to package them into a jar file...only production code is packaged into a jar file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you said about the Maven [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) is true. The "main" phases include:

- `compile`: in this phase, the [`maven-compiler-plugin:compile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) goal is run which compiles the main code of the project.
- `test-compile`: in this phase, the [`maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html) goal is run which compiles the test code of the project.
- `test`: in this phase, the [`maven-surefire-plugin:test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) goal is run and all the unit tests are executed.
- `package`: in this phase, the [`maven-jar-plugin:jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) goal is run and creates a JAR of the current project. By default, this JAR will include all classes under `target/classes`, which contains all the main classes, but not the test classes which are located inside `target/test-classes`. You could say that it is at this step that Maven ignores the test classes.
- `install`: in this phase, the [`maven-install-plugin:install`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) will install the main artifact, and every attached artifact, into your local repository.

To answer more precisely, it's not that Maven ignores the test classes, it is that by default, the packaging process only considers the main classes. But you can configure it to also package the test classes with the [`maven-jar-plugin:test-jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) goal inside another attached artifact.